# sym link for android-studio/bin/studio.sh

Tags: symlink, readlink

I tried creating a symbolic link for android studio as such

`sudo ln -s android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/bin/asw`

I chose `asw` as the keyword to hopefully launch the executable `studio.sh` from anywhere on my machine, but the link is not working.

```
~$ asw
No command 'asw' found, did you mean:
asw: command not found
```

I tried following the same convention for the python interpeter symbolic link

```
/usr/bin$ ll | grep "python"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root       9 May 25 00:04 python -> python2.7
```

Do I have to first add `studio.sh` to my `/usr/bin` directory?
i.e. for Python:

```
/usr/bin$ readlink -f python
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: Welcome to this site. You should use absolute path in command`ln -s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `ln -s` needs a fully specified (absolute) path.  And I recommend you to make such a link in `~/bin` or at least `/usr/local/bin` (both of them are expected to be present in your `PATH`), because files in `/usr/bin` might conflict with other commands installed by distribution's packages.

Try something like this:

```
sudo ln -sf $PWD/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/asw
```

Then check a path it actually linked to:

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/asw
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Jul  9 20:51 /usr/local/bin/asw -> /home/you/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```